# Как в node.js 8.0 ввести данные из консоли?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Решаю контест, в первый раз в жизни столкнулся с тем, что надо к моему коду на js приделать ввод данных.

То есть, то, что я на C++ пишу как

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    int main() {
        string str;
        cin >> str;
        cout << str;
        return 0;
    }
```

нужно написать в терминах Ноды.

Пробую так:

```
const readline = require('readline');
const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  })


rl.question('', (answer) => {
  console.log(answer)
  rl.close();
});
```

Но тестирующая система на мою такую попытку ругается.

(в моём реальном коде межуд вводом данных и выводом результата есть еще вычисления, но проблема не в них, скорее всего)

Как на Ноде написать обыкновенный ввод из консоли?

Comment: S.H., имейте ввиду, что 8мая нода очень отличается от современной. Из фундаментального: там иначе работают потоки, например.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего, проблема в пустом первом параметре rl.question().
Вот так у меня работает.

```
let readline = require('readline'); 
let rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
    prompt: '>'
});
rl.prompt();
rl.on('line', (input) => {
  input = input.toLowerCase();
  console.log(input);
  rl.close();
});
```

Comment: Спасибо! возможно, это решение проблемы :-)

Comment: @S.H. пожалуйста, пометьте ответ принятым, если он вам помог

Comment: В общем, удивительная вещь. Нода - дико популярная вещь, и множество людей - и я, в том числе, - используют её на уровне обезьян. И нет ни одного руководства, в котором черным по белому было бы написано "маличики - сиплюсплюсники, сейчас мы познакомимся с отличиями событИйного программирования на ноде от привычноого вам мира императивного программирования..."

Comment: @S.H., Да перестаньте, тоже самое, и плюсы куда мудрёнее, чем простой наглядный код js. Единственная трудность, - это большое количество неактуальных гайдов (это присуще многим языкам: JAVA, PHP, и тем же плюсам и шарпу). Язык очень древний и за свою историю несколько раз эволюционировал в подходах. А старые подходы не только бесполезны - они ещё и вредны. Но влиться легко в это русло. Можете попробовать Go - он что-то между JS и чистыми сями.

Comment: @DiD - спасибо, очень приятно получить ответ от знающего человека, плюсы хорошо именно там, что из них можно строить системы очень разной архитектуры. Спасибо за советы, буду продолжать :-)